# Recursion does not work with one line solution

Tags: c#, recursion

The question is about [Leetcode 938](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/description/).

My first solution is

```
return root == null ? 0 : root.val < low || root.val > high ? RangeSumBST(root.left, low, high) + RangeSumBST(root.right, low, high) : RangeSumBST(root.left, low, high) + RangeSumBST(root.right, low, high) + root.val;
```

And it is accepted.

Then I tried another one line solution for simplicity and readability

```
return root == null ? 0 : RangeSumBST(root.left, low, high) + RangeSumBST(root.right, low, high) + root.val < low || root.val > high ? 0 : root.val;
```

But it seems recursion doesn't work with the second solution. Only the most root value can be returned.

I would like to know what's the difference between these two solutions and why recursion does not work with the second solution.

Comment: You can try to add some parenthesis to clarify the precedence. And BTW I wouldn't write code that in actual projects due to poor readability.

Comment: Yep, I think in the second one, the presedence is probably `(RangeSumBST(root.left, low, high) + RangeSumBST(root.right, low, high) + root.val) < low || root.val > high ? ...` while it should be `RangeSumBST(root.left, low, high) + RangeSumBST(root.right, low, high) + (root.val < low || root.val > high ? ... )`

Comment: "for simplicity and readability". Everything above 120 chars in a line won't pass our review process without having a good reason to be longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other's answers ,let make it more simpler.

```
//solution #1
return  (condition) ? 
( constant value )  //check condition T then constant value add 0 
 : 
( constant value) + root.val; //check condition F then constant value add root.val


//solution #2
return  (( constant value ) + root.val ) < low|| root.val > high ?  
 0 // check new condition T then get only 0 
: 
root.val; // check new condition F then get only root.val
```

as @Fildor's answer you should add the parenthesis

```
return root == null ? 0 : ( RangeSumBST(root.left, low, high) + RangeSumBST(root.right, low, high) )   +  ( (root.val < low || root.val > high) ? 0 : root.val );
```